# Angular 2 route guard isn't waiting for value to be set

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-router, angular2-guards

I've got this route guard which should check the user's role as well as a `roleAccess` property defined in the route definition.

The problem I'm facing is that `.map` executes regardless of `accounts.isSelfPending`, only when that is false (it starts off as `null` in the `@ngrx/store`) should it allow `.map` to run.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** I realise that my question could be a bit vague, what I need is to wait for the user's information from a `/self` request that is fired higher up the the component hierarchy, and stored in the store.

The problem now is that the `/self` request isn't even being fired despite being fired in my `DashboardComponent`, which in turn holds the `AdsComponent` as one of it's children in the routing. (Which is the route I'm currently trying to lock with this guard).

Why isn't it even firing the `/self` request? Which I assume is part of this problem.

```
return this.store.select('accounts')
  .let((state: Observable<IAccountsStorage>) => state.filter((accounts: IAccountsStorage) => accounts.isSelfPending !== null && accounts.isSelfPending === false)))
  .map((accounts: IAccountsStorage) => {

    this.route.data.subscribe(
      data => {

        if (accounts.self) {

          if (accounts.self.role !== data['roleAccess'] && (data['roleAccess'] !== 0 || data['roleAccess'] !== undefined || data['roleAccess'] !== null)) {
            return this.router.navigateByUrl('admin/dashboard');
          }
          else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
).first();
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow your structure. Do you think you can make a Plunkr to repro the pb so I can try to help you ? :)

Comment: @Maxime I would if I had more time at the moment, however I managed to find a decent solution that'll do for now by going in another direction. As you can see in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a year later, but I had a similar issue with Stores and Guards in Angular. I *think* your issue has to do with the State initially having a `NULL` user object--even if only briefly as you set the user from an existing token.

That `NULL` comes through first but needs to be filtered out, like this:

```
canLoad(route: Route): Observable<boolean> | Promise<bolean> | boolean {
    return this.store.select(fromRoot.getUser)
        .filter(user => user != null) // ** THIS IS THE KEY TO SKIP NULL USER **
        .map(user => {
            //code t check user role
        }).take(1); // or .first() -- doesn't seem to be necessary for canActivate guards
}
```

NOTE: The code above reflects the current way Store code is written--or, at least, it's patterned after how the current `ngrx/store` 4.x [code examples](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app) are written, which is a different structure than used in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

After realising that using the store as the middle man was causing too much problems I decided to just call the api directly, ending up with a much clearer guard that actually works as intended.

I figured that this might help someone else so I'll leave the final solution here:

```
canLoad(): Observable<boolean> {

  return this.accountsApi.getSelf()
    .map(res => {

      if (res.data.role === 1) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return this.router.navigate(['admin/dashboard']);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return this.router.navigate(['admin/dashboard']);
  });
}
```

However, if someone knows how to solve the question with the original code please provide it as I'm curious how to actually do it using the store.